# How to properly use the "not" operator?

Tags: python, operator-keyword

I'm writing this program that is basically a limited calculator. I'm trying to make it so that if the user enters let's say "Power" instead of the number 1 for the desired mode, it prints out "Invalid selection". The same goes if they attempt to write "Quadratics" instead of 2 and so on for the rest.

```
#CALCULATOR
print("MY CALCULATOR")
print("1. Powers")
print("2. Quadratics")
print("3. Percents")
print("4. Basic Ops")
choice = int(input("Please enter your desired mode: "))
if choice == 1:
    base = int(input("Enter the base: "))
    exponent = int(input("Enter the exponent: "))
    power = base**exponent
if choice == 2:
    print("Please enter the values for A/B/C: ")
    a = int(input("A: "))
    b = int(input("B: "))
    c = int(input("C: "))
```

I tried doing:

```
if choice not == 1:
    print("Invalid Selection")
```

and

```
if choice not 1:
    print("Invalid Selection")
```

but they don't seem to work. If you could please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`not` is not a function. It is an operator.

The correct usage is to put it before an expression:

```
if not (choice == 1):
```

However in this case, it's much better to use `!=` (not equal) instead:

```
if choice != 1:
```